# Instantiate dynamic textfield

Tags: angular, material-design

We are creating an application with Angular 7 with Material Design (Not Angular Material!).

I'm loading some data after an Selectbox selection and with this i am trying to create a list, which has textfields in it.

```html
<ul class="mdc-list">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of ItemsHeaders; index as i">
    <li class="mdc-list-item">
      <div #mtf class="mdc-text-field">
        <input type="text" id="my-text-field" attr.name="{{item[0]}}" [ngModel]="item[0]" (ngModelChange)="valuechange(i, item[0], $event)" class="mdc-text-field__input">
        <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field">Name</label>
        <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__button" [disabled]="buttons[i] == 0" (click)="SaveColumn(item[0])">
        <span class="mdc-button__label"><i class="material-icons">save</i></span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

```
      this.ItemsHeaders = data;

      this.buttons = Array(data.length).fill(0);

      new MDCList(document.querySelector('.mdc-list'));

      var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-button');

      for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
        new MDCRipple(buttons[i])
      }
```

At the moment, i have set up a ViewChild:

```
  @ViewChildren('mtf') textfields;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.textfields.changes.subscribe(() => this.setupTextField());
  }

  setupTextField() {
    var textFields = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field');

    for (var i = 0; i < textFields.length; ++i) {
      new MDCTextField(textFields[i])
    }
  }
```

The Textfields seem to be instantiated, i can click on them and the effects are working, but the text (ngModel) seems to be activated afterwards, so it's not part of the instantiation. After i click on the textfield, it's showing up the right way.

The problem looks like the value is writing after the MDCTextField is initialized. What am i missing? Or is there another way to instantiate the Textfields after the data is loaded?

EDIT:

I have created a StackBlitz example, u can select something in the Selectbox and then you will see that the label from the textfield activates after you entered the textbox.

[StackBlitz](https://angular-dq7wxh.stackblitz.io)

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dq7wxh)

Comment: Try and add ngContentInit cycle for data manipulation and then instantiate your input field in the ngAfterViewInit cycle. This should help and can you please add a demo for the problem! It'll be easier to help then!

Comment: I have updated my question with the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just solved the problem you were facing!!

Here is the working demo! Enjoy :D

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyzsba

all that was needed to be done was to change the class from `mdc-floating-label` to `mdc-floating-label mdc-floating-label--float-above` when there is pre populated text.

The better / angular way would be:

```
[ngClass]="inputString.length>0?'mdc-floating-label mdc-floating-label--float-above':''"
```

Comment: Well i can live with that. Thanks! But shouldn't there also be an "angular way" of doing this?

Comment: There is actually!! you could use ngClass based on the length of the input string. If there is an input string, then you should apply these classes else do not apply them!!